# Using latest GCC5 or GCC6 to compile Android ROM and Kernel

Tags: android, linux, gcc

I recently started compiling my own kernel for Android Phone. The Linux Kernel version is 3.0.101. It's still very much stock... I have seen some developers use latest gcc5 (5.4.1) or gcc6 (6.1.1) to compile their kernels.

Google recommends to use GCC 4.9.

The question is, will compiling with the latest gcc improve the performance of the kernel? or maybe ROM in some way? Or stick with what Google recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a newer version of GCC will not necessarily improve the performance of your kernel, unless the newer versions provide new optimization options specifically for the CPU architecture of the phone you are compiling for. The reason Google is recommending version 4.8 is because this is the version they have tested with and know is stable. Using newer GCC releases probably won't hurt, but it probably won't help either. There is also the possibility that newer GCCs will have undiscovered or unresolved bugs that may negatively impact your kernel compile.

The short answer is, if your version of GCC is working to compile kernels that boot and run properly on your phone, there's little to nothing to be gained by upgrading to a newer version of GCC. The reason you see other developers using newer versions of GCC is most likely that these are the versions that were packaged with their Linux distros, and probably isn't even a conscious choice on their part.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Yeah, Stick with what works best for you. The part you last stated that is actually not true, these so called experienced devs create a build script to build the kernel. We can automate the whole process in here, We can manually choose to use custom compiler(say the latest GCC 6.2 for arm) and many more stuff. An example would be good right? Here it is: https://github.com/zaclimon/Quanta-Flo/blob/quanta-6.0/build.sh THANKS FOR REPLYING.